# Constructing functions from symbols using 'bquote' (or alternatives to doing so)

Tags: r, function, metaprogramming

Let's say I have an object of type "symbol" representing the name of a function. For example:

```r
nm <- quote(mean)
```

I want to construct a function `f` whose body *uses* the function named by the symbol `nm`. For example:

```r
f <- function(x, do = c("something", "nothing")) {
  switch(match.arg(do), something = mean(x), nothing = x)
}
```

I want to construct this function *identically*, which implies that I would *not* be satisfied with the following approach:

```r
factory <- function(name) {
  func <- match.fun(name)
  function(x, do = c("something", "nothing")) {
    switch(match.arg(do), something = func(x), nothing = x)
  }
}
g <- factory(nm)
```

since the body of `g` is not `body(f)` and the environment of `g` is not `environment(f)`.

One approach that I've considered is `bquote`:

```r
h <- eval(bquote({
  function(x, do = c("something", "nothing")) {
    switch(match.arg(do), something = .(nm)(x), nothing = x)
  }
}))
```

`bquote` gets me most of the way there, but one issue is that the `print` output of `h` doesn't contain the substituted value of `nm` by default:

```r
h
## function(x, do = c("something", "nothing")) {
##     switch(match.arg(do), something = .(nm)(x), nothing = x)
##   }

print(h, useSource = FALSE)
## function (x, do = c("something", "nothing")) 
## {
##     switch(match.arg(do), something = mean(x), nothing = x)
## }
```

The cause seems to be the `srcref` attribute of `h`:

```r
identical(f, h)
## [1] TRUE
identical(f, h, ignore.srcref = FALSE)
## [1] FALSE
```

**My question is:** How might one approach the general problem of constructing `f` from `nm`?

My conditions on the constructed function `h` are that `identical(f, h)` should be `TRUE` and that the output of `print(h)` should contain the substituted value of `nm`, similar to `print(f)`.

I would welcome answers improving on my existing `bquote` approach, or answers suggesting a new approach, or answers explaining why what I want to do is not actually possible...

Comment: Is your only concern with the srcref attribute that the function should have identical `print` output? Because then I'd actually recommend text processing of source code and `eval(parse())`. Or do you need the srcref environment also to be identical? I'm not sure that would be possible and thus `identical(f, h, ignore.srcref = FALSE)` wouldn't be `TRUE`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've edited the question to clarify what I consider to be a satisfactory answer. I don't need `identical(f, h, ignore.srcref = FALSE)` to be `TRUE` and I don't need `identical(capture.output(print(f)), capture.output(print(h)))` to be `TRUE` either.

Comment: `attributes(h) <- NULL`?

Comment: Ah - of course... I would accept an answer along that line, if you'd like to write one.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure that `attr(h, "srcref") <- NULL` is enough. See `?removeSource`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading through `?srcref`, it seems that there are two idiomatic ways to improve the `bquote` approach. The first uses `removeSource` to recursively clean a function that preserves its source code:

```r
h <- removeSource(eval(bquote({
  function(x, do = c("something", "nothing")) {
    switch(match.arg(do), something = .(nm)(x), nothing = x)
  }
})))
h
```

```
function (x, do = c("something", "nothing")) 
{
    switch(match.arg(do), something = mean(x), nothing = x)
}
```

The second avoids preserving the source code altogether:

```r
op <- options(keep.source = FALSE)
h <- eval(bquote({
  function(x, do = c("something", "nothing")) {
    switch(match.arg(do), something = .(nm)(x), nothing = x)
  }
}))
options(op)
h
```

```
function (x, do = c("something", "nothing")) 
{
    switch(match.arg(do), something = mean(x), nothing = x)
}
```

Actually, `?options` states that the default value of `keep.source` is `interactive()`, so both approaches are somewhat redundant in non-interactive contexts.

Answer (score 1):

Not especially elegant, but a `parse(deparse(` seems to work:

```
nm <- quote(mean)
f <- function(x, do = c("something", "nothing")) {
  switch(match.arg(do), something = mean(x), nothing = x)
}

eval(parse(text=deparse(bquote(h <- function(x, do = c("something", "nothing")) {
  switch(match.arg(do), something = .(nm)(x), nothing = x)
}))))

identical(f, h)
#> [1] TRUE
print(f)
#> function(x, do = c("something", "nothing")) {
#>   switch(match.arg(do), something = mean(x), nothing = x)
#> }
print(h)
#> function(x, do = c("something", "nothing")) {
#>     switch(match.arg(do), something = mean(x), nothing = x)
#> }
```

`srcref` is not identical, as expected:

```
identical(f, h, ignore.srcref = FALSE)
#> [1] FALSE
attributes(attributes(f)$srcref)$srcfile$lines
#> [1] "f <- function(x, do = c(\"something\", \"nothing\")) {"     
#> [2] "  switch(match.arg(do), something = mean(x), nothing = x)"
#> [3] "}"
attributes(attributes(h)$srcref)$srcfile$lines
#> [1] "h <- function(x, do = c(\"something\", \"nothing\")) {"     
#> [2] "    switch(match.arg(do), something = mean(x), nothing = x)"
#> [3] "}"
```

Comment: Thanks. This answer is instructive and meets my criteria, though I've stumbled on a couple of more transparent approaches.