# Pass a `chr` type argument and update the content of a nested function to return in R?

Tags: r, function

For a nested function such as

```r
fun_parent <- function(var) {
  fun_child <- function(x) {
    x + var
  }
  return(fun_child)
}
```

How can I customize the content of the returned function `fun_child` based on the input `var`?
For example,

```r
test <- fun_parent(var = "y")
print(test)
```

Desirable output:

```
function(x) {
  x + y
  }
<environment: xxxxxx>
```

Actual (undesirable) output:

```
function(x) {
    x + var
  }
<environment: 0x7f7f20126b70>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: As you may have guessed, the question described above is a simplified version of the actual question I had. The comment by Dan Adams prompted me to redefine my question. Then I realized that it would be hard to explain what I was really looking for without providing some context. So here is another reproducible example, still greatly simplified from my actual question, but with extra information.

Say I want to apply a model to a group of datasets using `purrr::map()`, and to construct the model based on user input:

```r
set.seed(1234)

df_demo <- data.frame(
  x1 = rnorm(100),
  x2 = rnorm(100),
  x3 = rnorm(100),
  y = rnorm(100),
  sex = factor(rep(c("f", "m"), each = 50))
  )

func <- function(var) {
  mod <- function(data) {
    lm(y ~ var, data = data) # var is supplied by users
  }

  output <- df_demo |>
    dplyr::group_by(group) |>
    tidyr::nest() |>
    dplyr::mutate(
      model = purrr::map(data, mod),
      tidy = purrr::map(model, broom::tidy)
    ) |>
    tidyr::unnest(tidy)

  return(output)
}

test <- func(var = "x1")
```

I also tried a variation of the version above:

```
df_demo <- ...

func <- function(var) {
  output <- df_demo |>
    dplyr::group_by(group) |>
    tidyr::nest() |>
    dplyr::mutate(model = purrr::map(data,
        function(data, ...) {
          lm(y ~ var, data = data)
        }),
      tidy = purrr::map(model, broom::tidy)
      ) |>
    tidyr::unnest(tidy)

  return(output)
}
test <- func(var = "x1")
```

Both versions failed to achieve the result I wanted.
An error was returned instead.
At first I thought it was because the input `var = "x1"` could not be passed into `fun` or into the nested function `mod`. That's when I posted the original question at the beginning of this post.

After seeing Dan Adams' comment, I tried to approach the question differently. Instead of supplying `var = "x1"`, I turned the entire `formula` into a parameter, like this:

```r
# func <- function(var) {
func <- function(formula) {
  output <- df_demo |>
    dplyr::group_by(group) |>
    tidyr::nest() |>
    dplyr::mutate(model = purrr::map(data,
        function(data, ...) {
          # lm(y ~ var, data = data)
          lm(formula, data = data)
        }),
      tidy = purrr::map(model, broom::tidy)
      ) |>
    tidyr::unnest(tidy)
  return(output)
}
# test <- func(var = "x1")
test <- func(formula = y ~ x1)
```

Lo & Behold, this worked!

```
> test
# A tibble: 4 × 8
# Groups:   group [2]
  group data              model  term        estimate std.error statistic p.value
  <fct> <list>            <list> <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
1 f     <tibble [50 × 6]> <lm>   (Intercept)   0.0675     0.170     0.398 0.692
2 f     <tibble [50 × 6]> <lm>   x1            0.0763     0.160     0.477 0.636
3 m     <tibble [50 × 6]> <lm>   (Intercept)  -0.106      0.124    -0.855 0.397
4 m     <tibble [50 × 6]> <lm>   x1            0.384      0.128     3.01  0.00419
```

This solution is not quite the same as the original one I had envisioned. However, it does seem more straightforward.

BTW, I am really overwhelmed (in a good way) by how quickly people responded to my original question with some brilliant ideas. I must admit that some of them seemed way over my head. Nevertheless, I am going to carefully review them and try my best to select one as the solution to my original question.

Comment: I think it makes more sense to define the `fun_child()` first, and then just call it as part of defining `fun_parent()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to have \`dput\` return source code that would run outside of the enclosing environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70476065/is-it-possible-to-have-dput-return-source-code-that-would-run-outside-of-the-e)

Comment: For you new question you may need to consider building an intermediate formula result with `as.formula`

Comment: @jpdugo17  Thank you for sharing the related question! I must admit that I don't understand the linked question well enough to know whether its solution applies to mine.

Comment: @IRTFM Thank you for this excellent tip!! I just looked up `as.formula`. It seems to be a very promising alternative.

Comment: @chunyun I would recommend `reformulate` over `as.formula` if you want to support strings as arguments.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to pull a value from the object list based on a name given as a character, then the `get` function suffices.

```
 fun_parent <- function(var) {
     force(var)
     fun_child <- function(x) {
         x + get(var)
     }
     return(fun_child)
 }
 test <- fun_parent(var = "y")
 print(test)

#function(x) {
#        x + get(var)
#    }
#
#<environment: 0x5654f87a1ae8>
Y=6
test(4)
#[1] 10
z=10

test <- fun_parent(var = "z")
print(test)
#function(x) {
#        x + get(var)
#   }
#<bytecode: 0x5654f7eac430>
#<environment: 0x5654f7637bb8>
test(4)
#[1] 14
```

The value of z is not stored in the `test` function, only the name is.

```
 z = 20
 test(4)
[1] 24
```

But is you want to see how that happens you need to look at the environment itself since the body was not evaluated:

```
> test
function(x) {
        x + get(var)
    }
<bytecode: 0x5654f7eac430>
<environment: 0x5654f7637bb8>
> environment(test)$var
[1] "z"
```

I was a bit surprised that substituting `"x"` for the value of `var` succeeded, but I wasn't suprised that using an object name that I knew was in my workspace did work:

```
> environment(test)$var <- "x"
> test(4)
[1] 8
> x     # only existed in the parameter list but was stored in the environment
Error: object 'x' not found  
> environment(test)$var <- "y"
> test(4)
[1] 10
```

user554330
correctly points out that the name of the object to which var points could be changed. If you wnat to lock in the name you would need to evaluate the "gotten" name:

```
fun_parent <- function(var) {
     fun_child <- function(x) {
         x + force(get(var))
     }
     return(fun_child)
 }
 test <- fun_parent(var = "y")
 print(test)
#function(x) {
#       x + force(get(var))
#    }
#<environment: 0x565514c4ae38>
 test(4)
#[1] 10
 fy <-  fun_parent(var = "y")
 fz <-  fun_parent(var = "z")
 y=10
 z=20
 fy(4)
#[1] 14
 fz(4)
#[1] 24
 ls( environment(fy) )
#[1] "fun_child" "var"      
 environment(fy)$var 
#[1] "y"
  environment(fz)$var 
#[1] "z"
```

Comment: Watch out for lazy evaluation:  you didn't evaluate `var` before returning `fun_child`, so its value may change.  Try `var <- "y"; fy <- fun_parent(var); var <- "z"; fz <- fun_parent(var)`.  After that sequence, `fy` will try to get `z`, not `y`.

Comment: I guess it depends on what level of indirection is desired. The goals were not really specified. If you had named the function `plus_var` then it might be behaving as desired.

Comment: I think it's reasonable to assume the OP wanted a function that didn't give unintended results sometimes.  The fix is easy:  just evaluate `var` before returning `fun_child`.

Comment: I've edited a fix into the function definition.  The names are irrelevant; what matters is when the `var` argument is first evaluated.  `force(var)` triggers evaluation.

Comment: OK. I had tried both `eval` and `force`. I used eval because I thought that was your suggestion, but `force` is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your edit.  I fixed the first version of `fun_parent`, but the second needs fixing too.  You need to evaluate `var` in `fun_parent`, not only in `fun_child`.

Answer (score 2):

I asked a related but not identical question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70287497). Here are two options using `bquote`:

```r
f <- function(varname) {
  removeSource(eval(bquote(function(x) x + .(as.name(varname)))))
}
f("y")
```

```
function (x) 
x + y
<environment: 0x1128976b0>
```

```r
op <- options(keep.source = FALSE)
g <- function(varname) {
  eval(bquote(function(x) x + .(as.name(varname))))
}
options(op)
g("y")
```

```
function (x) 
x + y
<environment: 0x110491580>
```